# Schedule Email Reports for Google Analytics Web + App Property

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-firebase

As we know Google Analytics allows a user to email reports automatically if the property has a view configured. Please check the screenshoot: [Property-view-share-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP31G.png)

As you can see from the above image, there is a share option where we can schedule emails and send reports. But why can not i achieve the same when we have the Property set to App + Web? Please check the screenshot: [App + Web-share-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbMTJ.png). There is no schedule email option in this. I have looked around the internet but was unable to find a solution. As i have no View option in App + Web property i am unable to use Google Spreadsheet Add-Ons as well. So i would like to know if it is possible to schedule emails for  the new App + Web property report of Google Analytics.